# Expected value: CLOSED, actual value: "CLOSED"

Tags: linux, bash, jq

I am trying to create automated test and I do not understand why this happens, the error is:

```
Test case: Verify that circuit breaker has status CLOSED -> Test FAILED, EXPECTED VALUE: CLOSED, ACTUAL VALUE: "CLOSED", WILL ABORT
```

Why does it not compare Strings even if they are? I am new to bash scripting so this is probably something pretty obvious.

Function which is calling Spring Boot Actuator
My code looks like:

```
function testCircuitBreaker() {

  echo "Start Circuit Breaker Test"
  EXEC="docker run --rm -it --network=my-network alpine"

  #Verify that circuit breaker is closed via health endpoint
  assertEqual "CLOSED" "$($EXEC wget movie-composite:8080/actuator/health -qO - | jq .components.movieCircuitBreaker.details.state)" "Verify that circuit breaker has status CLOSED"

  #Three slow calls to get TimeoutException
  for ((n = 0; n < 3; n++)); do
    assertCurl 500 "curl -k https://$HOST:$PORT/movie-composite/MOV_ID_REVS_RECS?delay=3 $AUTH -s"
    message=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq -r .message)
    assertEqual "Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 2000ms" "${message:0:57}"
  done
}
```

Assertion Function:

```
function assertEqual() {

  local expected=$1
  local actual=$2
  local message=$3

  printf "Test case: $message -> "

  if [ "$actual" = "$expected" ]; then
    echo "Test OK (actual value: $actual)"
    return 0
  else
    echo "Test FAILED, EXPECTED VALUE: $expected, ACTUAL VALUE: $actual, WILL ABORT"
    return 1
  fi
}
```

Comment: Try running your script with `-x` i.e. as `bash -x <script-name>` to see much more detailed view of the intermediate values. Also the script has multiple false practices.

Comment: The strings you're comparing aren't equal, though...

Comment: @MateuszGebroski: Your `$actual` value contains double quotes; your `$expected` does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) outputs well-formed JSON by default, so strings will be quoted. As an example:

```
$ jq .foo <<<'{"foo":"bar"}'
"bar"
```

Therefore your `assertEqual "CLOSED" "$(... | jq .components.movieCircuitBreaker.details.state)" ...` command is comparing `CLOSED` with `"CLOSED"` (note the extra quotes). You could quote the expected string, as @rtx13 suggests, but I think it's clearer to have `jq` output just the contents of the field. You can do that with the `--raw-output` flag:

> With this option, if the filter's result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.

```
$ jq -r .foo <<<'{"foo":"bar"}'
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try preserving the quotes around CLOSED by changing:

```sh
  assertEqual "CLOSED" "$($EXEC wget movie-composite:8080/actuator/health -qO - | jq .components.movieCircuitBreaker.details.state)" "Verify that circuit breaker has status CLOSED"
```

to

```sh
  assertEqual '"CLOSED"' "$($EXEC wget movie-composite:8080/actuator/health -qO - | jq .components.movieCircuitBreaker.details.state)" "Verify that circuit breaker has status CLOSED"
```

The single quotes around `"CLOSED"` preserve the quotation marks when passed to the `assertEqual` function.